# Separate the isolated points

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a set in topological space $X$ such that every point of $A$ is an isolated point.

**I want to find a family of disjoint open sets $\{U_x\}$ such that $U_x$ is neighborhood of $x$**

If $X$ is a metric space, this is easy. Because for each $x\in A$, there exist a 
$r_x>0$ such that $B(x,r_x)\cap (A\setminus \{x\})=\emptyset$. 
Then we can set $U_x=B(x,\frac{r_x}{2})$ and it is difficult to find that they are disjoint.

If $X$ is merely a Hausdorff space, this is not true. Let us consider the famous exmaple $\mathbb{R}_K$. 
https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorff_not_implies_regular

The underlying set is the reals, and the basis is chosen as the usual open intervals, along with all sets of the form $(a,b)\setminus K$, where $K=\{\frac{1}{n}; n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

If we set $A=K\cup\{0\}$, then we couldn't find disjoint open sents as descried above to separate the points in $A$.

So, my question is

**What is the "optimal" condition for exitsence of such open sets ? Normal? reuglar? Say, if $(X,\tau)$ is merely a normal/regular topology and $A$ consists of only isolated points, then is it always possible to find a family of disjoint open neighborhood $U_x$ of every point $x\in A$?**

**PS: Please don't misunderstand what I mean and change the topology $\tau$ to $2^X$.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space $X$ where for any discrete subspace $A \subseteq X$ (so $A$ such that $\{x\}$ is open in $A$ for all $x \in A$, so discrete in the subspace topology) we have pairwise  disjoint open sets $U_x$ of $X$ such that $x \in U_x$, is called **collectionwise Hausdorff**.

So this is exactly the condition you need. In [this blog post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/bings-example-g/) there is a discussion of Bing's classic example $G$. This space $G$ is completely normal (all subspaces are normal) but $G$ is not collectionwise Hausdorff. It is well-known that all paracompact Hausdorff spaces are collectionwise normal (this includes all metric spaces as you said). Example $H$ (also by Bing) is even perfectly normal, so it's a strong condition, not even implied by the one of strongest forms of normality. A related notion is that of collectionwise normality, also discussed on the linked blog.